# maven: how to include annotation-generated .java files in the .jar

Tags: java, maven, gwt, xtend

I have some java 7 annotation processors (for xtend) on my class-path. Via some annotations they create java files.
This works great, in Elipse and in the Maven build.

The generated files end up in `target/generated-sources/annotations` as expected.
The corresponding generated `.class` files also end up where expected and are thus part of the final jar file.

Since I need to also include all java source files in my `.jar` file (there should be only one `.jar` file with the sources *and* classes) for GWT,
I have specified `src/main/java` as a resources dir (so that Maven copies the files to the classes dir and they end up in the jar file).

the trick with the resources directory does not really work for my generated files, because Maven will first copy all resources and then start the compilation (which in turn will generate the `.java` files via the annotation processors).

How can I tell Maven to copy also include the generated `.java` files in the `.jar`?

Comment: You could bind the `generate-sources` plugin to a phase prior to resources?

Comment: In what location in the project structure do your generated .java files reside?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup but the generate-sources plugin does produce a separate .jar called xxx-sources, right? (but maybe that's the cleaner approach anyway)
@JamesB they are in `target/generated-sources/annotations` (as already mentioned?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the `maven-resources-plugin` to the `prepare-package` phase to achieve copying annotation sources before packaging proper:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-annotations</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/annotations</directory>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
    ...
```

I hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: that's true for the generated-sources phase (where the xtend plugin will create some java files). but as mentioned above, this does already work. the problem is that the java 7 annotation processors will be run during the *compile* phase (after the xxx-resources phase).
and so all .java files generated by those annotation-processors will be missing.

Comment: Ooops! Sorry I missed that. Still, the basic idea is sound - you just need to bind `copy-resources` to a phase after compile. I have amended the answer accodingly.

Comment: thanks. this works. I just had to add another configuration paramter for the output-directory like this: `<outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>`